# How to calculate trading fees ahead of time?

Tags: api, bitstamp

I'd like to determine what trading fees to expect before placing an order.

According to https://www.bitstamp.net/fee_schedule/ Bitstamp's trading fees depend upon the USD total of a customer’s last 30 days worth of transactions.

How can one calculate this amount using [the Bitstamp API](https://www.bitstamp.net/api/)? It doesn't seem to be possible.

Answer (score 1):

Those are Bitstamp trading fees, not Bitcoin transaction fees. Trading fees are automatically calculated and deducted by Bitstamp when executing a trade.

For choosing the right Bitcoin fee, use `bitcoin-cli estimatesmartfee` or one of the many web services.

Comment: That's not what I meant. I need to know what the Bitstamp trading fees are before placing an order in order to estimate the profit of a trade. It doesn't make sense for a service to charge you a fee without letting you know what it will be ahead of time.

Answer (score 1):

Every exchange has a predetermined fee structure for any financial transaction that you perform on the exchange. Also this fee is subject to the volume you have traded.

From the links you have provided, the API documentation page contains the user transactions section which would return the list of all transactions you have done. 
You can filter out the last 30days transactions and get the USD volume from that.

Comment: That's nice but you didn't answer my question.

Comment: I'm sorry I did not check the links provided by you. I have updated the answer. @Gili

Comment: also the api returns the fee rates as well.

Answer (score 1):

From the API documentation available at https://www.bitstamp.net/api/

The private endpoint `https://www.bitstamp.net/api/v2/balance/` includes the fees for all pairs.

The private endpoint `https://www.bitstamp.net/api/v2/balance/{currency_pair}/` includes the fee for the specified pair.

Comment: Are you saying that the fee returned by the balance api adjusts the fee in response to the 30 day trailing volume?

Comment: @Gili It's a private endpoint so I would assume so